# Default Location of JTL file for Jmeter Test Execution

Tags: jmeter

I forgot to provide JTL file path in my reports (Listeners) when I start jmeter test.

Test summary and View result tree data are available in JMeter GUI screen. I suspect that these information will be stored in somewhere in local machine. How I should extract this? JMeter does have any default location to store this JTL data, if we didn't provide?

I have checked jmeter.properties to find out any default location. No clue. It would be grateful, somebody help to extract the test result.

Thanks,
Farook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JLT file is not saved by default. you will have to give the file path and re-run your tests to capture your results.